# How can i add here a webview?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, webview

what should I do here working my script, I've tried everything but nothing works.. he give's a error by webview?

```
package com.dehvb.dehvbapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class ProgrammaFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_programma, container, false);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProgrammaFragment extends Fragment {
    Webview wv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_programma, container, false);
        wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourWebviewId);

        //Use the thread policy only if your load URL doesn't work on main thread.
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        wv.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

P.s. take off `import com.dehvb.deheerenveenseboys.R;` from the import, it can cause some problems.

Comment: he's give a error by ""wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Webview1);"" I should add one of these two "" create constant 'webview1' in type 'id' "" or "" Create field 'webview1' in type 'id' ??

Comment: In yours fragment_programma you need to have a webview with id="@+id/webview1" and in your class: wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);

Comment: I have done that you might look for me where it goes wrong with me? I can upload it for you?

Comment: Update your answer posting your xml file and your logcat

Comment: i can't find my logcat, So here is the script https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dxAopnSoICeUlXeFFJTzd2dDA&authuser=0

Comment: you have access to the file

Comment: @Hessel man, you have not to use "http://www.example.com" but the url that you want to load..

Comment: it is now wrong by findViewById, I'm doing it all wrong??

Comment: Wait you can't change the question adding more code? Because it is another question. My answer was for your first question, stop.

Answer (score 0):

If your have already have webview in your layout file than just use directly!

```
WebView wb = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
wb.loadUrl(url);
```

replace url with your web url like "https://stackoverflow.com/".
Hope this helped!

EDIT:
First update your manifest exactly like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dehvb.dehvbapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dehvb.dehvbapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and your ProgrammaFragment.class

```
public class ProgrammaFragment extends Fragment
{
WebView wv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_programma, container, false);
    wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.WebView1);

    //Use the thread policy only if your load URL doesn't work on main thread.
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    wv.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

    return rootView;
}
}
```

I have tested it, i can post screenshot if you want!

Comment: So check my solution with ThreadPolicy i think it could be for that!

Comment: Download this code and try again : [Demo](http://a5e2fba00d8bcb729d89839f.javacodegeeks.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/AndroidWebViewExample.zip)

Comment: I do not get it working, you might look for me what I am doing wrong? then I post my files

Comment: These are the only changes I had done in the code given by you in drive.google.com.... just take some time to see what are the changes, you can just replace this content in related files in your project and check it!